# Java: Sending/Recieving Udp packet in Device being behind wi-fi router

Tags: java, android, networking, udp, router

**I want to**

1. Recieve UDP message on device when it is connected through wi-fi
2. Know how to send udp message on device when it is connected to wi-fi
       router as the sender on diffrent network

**What i have tried**
 http://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP

**What is working**

1. UDP messeges are being recieved on device when it is connected
   through 2g/3g data service
2. UDP messeges are being recieved when sender and reciever are both in
       same network ( behind wi-fi router )

Any help/point in right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the device is behind a wi-fi router, it has a private address so it isn't reachable from outside the private network, at least no without some extra work.

You need to do [Hole Punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching), is what applications like Skype do to receive UDP packets. Applications usually use a STUN server in order to achieve this.

The easiest alternative would be to have a server with a public address and make all the devices connect to the server with tcp/ip protocol. If you can't afford that you need to do Hole Punching.

Comment: Would HolePunching do the trick ??? any good tutorial on this ?? i am googling holepunching anyway :). will mark is as accepted as soon as will understand holepunching :).

Comment: Hole Punching will do the trick, but I don't think it's easy to implement. Perhaps you can find java libraries that implement this.

Comment: for now i have put it away and working on something else but as i will again start working on this.ill tell the procedure i'll end up following. :) thanks ones again for direction